# safe way to mix use of mmap(2) and malloc(3), requires that: the result of mmap(2) must be continuous

Tags: c, garbage-collection, malloc, mmap

What am I doing is a garbage collector, using `mmap(2)` to allocate space for user space, this requires that when initially allocate, it could start from anywhere, but the following allocation address should be continuous with preceding allocation, like following:

```
page_size = getpagesize();
heap.start_addr = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);
heap.size = page_size;

//when we need more spaces
mmap(heap.start_addr + heap.size, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
     MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);//have MAP_FIXED set
heap.size += page_size;
```

but when we doing gc, we may need some auxiliary data structure to store some information, we want to use `malloc(3)` to allocate space for us, but I don't know if this could lead some confliction to make `mmap(2)` failed, what is the best way to do so?

Comment: mmap doesn't necessarily create memory at the address specified. It only takes it as a hint, and create memory space at the page boundary nearby. If you use memory space by malloc, mmap will skip the space and use the page right after the one used by malloc. The actual address is returned.

Comment: @texasbruce I see, so the best and portable way to do this is by using  some algorithm doesn't require continuous memory, right?

Comment: yes. for example, the space malloc-ed has a pointer in the overhead and it points to the next available space so that malloc knows where to search for space next

Answer (score 0):

I see, so the best and portable way to do this is by using some algorithm doesn't require continuous memory, right? –  xudifsd

yes. for example, the space malloc-ed has a pointer in the overhead and it points to the next available space so that malloc knows where to search for space next –  texasbruce

Answer (score 0):

If you want contiguous addresses, you could pre-allocate at start time a large chunk (e.g. a gigabyte on 32 bits machines, a petabyte on 64 bits machines) of address space using the `MAP_NORESERVE` option of [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html); you'll then get (on `mmap` success) a huge range of address space which won't be given to future `mmap` calls without `MAP_FIXED`, and this includes `mmap` called by [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). That space does not eat any swap area (so using it by dereferencing for write pointers into it could give `SIGSEGV` ....).

It looks like [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) (1.2.4 on Debian/Sid/x86-64) is using such a trick -at least according to [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

Later on, to actually get some chunk of that range, you'll use `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` (and *without* `MAP_NORESERVE`) *inside* that range (on a reasonably sized segment, since that eats swap space).

But I would suggest instead to code a GC which does not suppose that it is working in a single address segment.